# ROS Raspberry Pi <-> PC Communication error

Tags: gmapping, ros-noetic

I'm asking this question because I'm trying to get LiDAR sensor values from a home-made robot using a Raspberry Pi and run SLAM on a PC, but I'm having trouble running it.

Raspberry Pi and PC are connected via LAN cable, and both ROS_HOST_NAME and ROS_MASTER_URI have been set.

[image]

Connected to Raspberry Pi with VNC Viewer.
When running LIDAR and odom node SLAM on Raspberry Pi, it operates normally as above.
However, mapping speed is very slow.

[image]
This is rqt_graph executed on Raspberry Pi.

[image]
This error occurs when remotely connecting to an Ubuntu PC.

[image]
This is rqt_graph run on Ubuntu.

Comment: The problem was solved by synchronizing the PC and Raspberry Pi time. thank you

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have moved my comment to the answer section just to make it an answer for furture readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange!

Please make sure that both machines are time synchronized. Time synchronization is crucial in a multi-machine setup.